# Mbed: some basic questions

Tags: mbed

I am new in MbedOS.

I am so confused about following questions.

1. What's the difference between yotta and CLI?

2. How do I port the MbedOS to my board?

3. What's the difference between Mbed 2.0 and 3.0?

Thank you..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answers inline

> 1. What's the difference between yotta and CLI?

Yotta is the build tool used to build mbed v3 projects. mbed CLI is the tool used to build mbed v5 projects. The breif history is v3 was not backwards compatible with v2, aka mbed classic, so we took the best parts of v3 and the best parts of v2 and put them together to form mbed v5. In mbed v5, just like in v2 you can use the online compiler (https://developer.mbed.org/compiler) or you can compile offline. The tool known as mbed CLI is the same tool that sits behind the online compiler, its just been wrapped up so you can use it on your machine if you prefer. (ie you can run `mbed compile` on your machine instead of clicking the `compile` button on the online compiler)

> 2. How do I port the MbedOS to my board?

Vendors are in the process of adding mbed OS 5.0 support to most of the mbed boards on the website. If your board isn't supported yet then hold tight, it will be soon. If you want to add support for a board you have created then you can apply via the mbed enabled program (https://www.mbed.com/en/about-mbed/mbed-enabled/).

> 3. What's the difference between Mbed 2.0 and 3.0?

mbed 2.0, also known as mbed classic, was an abstraction layer that made it easy to use traditional microcontroller peripherals. mbed 3.0 introduced an interrupt driven OS along with some really awesome improvements for low power and full stack IoT development. mbed 5.0 takes the best parts of both and combines them in a way that is backwards compatible with mbed 2.0. The biggest difference between 3.0 and 5.0 is the underlying thing in 3.0 was interrupt driven while the underlying bits in 5.0 is the Keil RTX v5 RTOS.